# Big Paging Problem

Tags: ajax, multithreading, jsp, servlets, paging

My result page needs to be paged. But I have some problems.

I get results from a web service (not mine), about 1 000 000 objects. But in 1 000 000 objects, there are some objects with their status is DELETED (I can't filter it when I call web service, I just can filter it when I get them down). For example, 200 000 objects have their status is DELETED, so total right items I have is 800 000.

Problem: I must get all of them down, and do something to filter to get the number of total items is 800 000. So It is slow.

Do you have a perfect solutions than me. Thanks

Comment: The perfect solution is to make it fast. Without knowing your code, what is slow in the code, and what's the relationship between paging and the slowness problem, it's impossible to help.

Comment: Talk to the web service owner.  The only thing you can do is buy a faster Internet pipe.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're looping through the objects, you can always just ignore the items where `(obj.status=="DELETED")`